# Automatically receive answer no submit button

Tags: php

I have a form using which i am going to calculate two numbers.

Right now, when i click the submit  button, only then I get the answer.
However, what I want is that whenever I put the values inside the boxes, then the answer should appear automaticallly.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculate</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">

Number 1:
<input type="number" name="no1" />

Number 2:
<input type="number" name="no2" />

<input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
= <?php

@$no1 = $_POST['no1'];

@$no2 = $_POST['no2'];

echo $result = $no1 + $no2;


?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use jquery for that..

Comment: This is what javascript does best

Comment: can u write some sources for this one please or give me please the exact code

Comment: @user3475078 Look into [jQuery $.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) if you want to do the computation server-side (if you need database access, want to hide the implementation, etc.). If it's a simple computation, it is best to do so with Javascript itself, rather than server-side.

Comment: You can use jquery to achieve your purpose. For this, what you can do is that- put an onblur event and the answer will appear automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
<input type="number" id="a" value="50">+
<input type="number" id="b" value="50">=
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: @user3702775: i need a third box for dividing how to do that ?

Comment: Create another output and calculate value in same way as above
E.g. - for output with name y
`y.value=parseInt(a.value)/parseInt(b.value)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to study the difference between server-side scripting and client-side scripting, I think.

What you seem to want is for the user's browser to do the calculation work. In that case, you will write your code in javascript (I suggest looking up jQuery, which is a javascript framework). Then you can do exactly what you are asking.

Look up the `onKeyPress` event for your inputs.

I searched ["javascript onkeypress calculate" on google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript%20onkeypress%20calculate&safe=off) and saw some results that might help.